# Increment inside angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, increment

I am trying to show some `div`s (which are under 3+ `ng-repeat`s) conditionally and then increment a counter variable which. The counter contributes in the conditions which decide the visibility of divs.

When I do something similar to`ng-show='foo++ < SOME_LIMIT'` I get a syntax error:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN of the expression [moveItem.type != 'account' && team.rowCount++] starting at [moveItem.type != 'account' && team.rowCount++].
```

or

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '2' is an unexpected token at column 42 of the expression [team.expandAccounts || team.rowCount++ < 2] starting at [2]
```

Giving the code doesn't seem to be required but still I am giving what I was trying.
I tried something similar to:

```
<div ng-repeat='request in pagedRequests'
  <tr ng-repeat='(fooId, foo) in returnFoos(request)'>
    <td ng-init='foo.rowCount = 0'>
      {{foo.someAttribute}}
      <!--Here is just an icon shown when the rowCount reaches some limit, say 3.
          Uses ng-switch on foo.rowCount. Skipping this as this doesn't seem
          problematic. This toggles rows' collapsing using foo.expandRows.-->
      <div ng-repeat='bar in foo.bars'
           ng-show='foo.rowCount < 3 || foo.expandRows'>
        <span ng-show='bar.type=="multiRowBar"'
              ng-repeat='row in bar.rows'>
          <span ng-show="foo.expandRows || foo.rowCount++ < 3"> <!--SYNTAX ERROR!-->
            <!--Showing the nested objects with more ng-repeats.-->
        </span>
        <span ng-show='bar.type!="multiRowBar" && foo.rowCount++<3'>  <!--SYNTAX ERROR!-->
          <!-- This adds a single row per bar of this type.-->
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Is it that we can't use post/pre increment/decrement operators (like `++`) inside angular expressions?

Comment: Could you make use of the $index object that you get when you use an ng-repeat?

Comment: @dskh: yes that would involve `$parent.$index + $index < 3`. I am just trying to avoid `$parent` in a template.

Comment: Also the icon which depends on the `rowCount` goes complex as it would then depend on child's index.

Comment: Why would you want to do this. Like any other expression in angular, the ng-show expression may get evaluate many times, hence you would have unwanted side effects.

Comment: @Chandermani: Right, I figured that out.

Comment: @0xc0de: That's true, but you cannot use increment operators on `ng-click` expressions, either, which is annoying. I had to replace `ng-click="foo++"` with `ng-click="foo = foo + 1"` to get it to work. This seems like an arbitrary omission from AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ignorant to the fact that such an effort triggers cyclic `$digest` calls which breaks. (Just for the sake of making some sense out of this question I'm giving my solution. Hope it will help someone trying this stuff) The solution I finalized involved flattening all the lists to a single list and `switch`ing to show the icon for a particular value of `$index`.

Answer (score 2):

Why just do not use method like:

```
<button ng-show='increaseFoo() < SOME_LIMIT'>press  me</button>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.SOME_LIMIT = 10;     
$scope.foo = 8; 

$scope.increaseFoo = function(){
    return $scope.foo++;
};
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/496/)**</kbd>

if `$scope.foo = 8;`, `ng-show` returns `true`

if `$scope.foo = 9;`, `ng-show` returns `false`

Comment: Seeing this after a long time, just want to clear that I am not the downvoter (it may seem from the fact that I myself have answered my question).

Comment: Upvoted, but would prefer a no-function solution and no-$index either (I'm trying to increment tabindex in a form, so the more controller-agnostic the better)