# Increment/decrement into angular expression (id generation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auto-increment

I want to do increment in nested ng-repeats like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="arr in extension.providers">
     <div id="pos{{++providerId}}"
          ng-repeat="provider in arr track by provider.id">
     </div>
</div>
```

Where

```
$scope.providerId = 0;
```

But I get error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '+' not a primary expression at column 11 of the expression ['pos' + (providerId++)] starting at [+providerId)].
```

I tried write increment in function, like in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912683/increment-inside-angular-expression), but got id's like "pos398", "pos400" etc.

How can I generate id's on my webpage?

Comment: you can't put counting logic on view in angular. it will run hundred or thousand times, proportional to $watchers count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question:

```
<div ng-repeat="arr in extension.providers" ng-init="topIndex = $index">
     <div id="pos{{topIndex.toString() + $index.toString()}}"
          ng-repeat="provider in arr track by provider.id">
     </div>
</div>
```

As result, I get unique id's like pos00, pos01, pos10, pos11....

Thanks [Chrillewoodz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4054974/chrillewoodz) and [Beyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202913/beyers) for their help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an `ng-repeat` to generate the `div` elements which I'm assuming you can simply use the `$index` of the loop to generate IDs.

In your case you have nested `ng-repeat`, so if you want to access the parent `$index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="arr in extension.providers">
  <div ng-repeat="provider in arr track by provider.id" id="pos{{$parent.$index}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can simply just use `$index` as demonstrated by this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d8YPSHqLYkPtqovGpxbv?p=preview

Comment: By sad, it isn't working. I have id="pos1" on all elements.

Comment: @Salasar Are you using it inside an ng-repeat or?

Comment: Nested ng-repeats, then I can't use $index. Your answer don't have saving changed value in variable, then how providerId can be unique?

Comment: @Salasar You're going to have to show us more of your code if you want proper help.

Comment: @Salasar For nested `ngrepeat`, use `ng-init="topIndex = $index"` on the outer `ngrepeat` line. This is all documented.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I updated my question, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @Salasar Which ng-repeat's index do you want to use?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz it's irrelevant, I want to get unique string + digit Id due to $index or not. Therefore I didn't describe it in first edition of my question.

Comment: @Salasar You are going to have to use $index. There is no other option that won't make angular crash.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz below I add my solution based on your and Beyers advices. Thanks for your help!